# Why isn't the destructor of this class being invoked?

Tags: qt, destructor, qthread

I have two classes - one that runs in the main thread and performs GUI operations and another that performs some calculations and makes network requests.

```
// A member of the class that runs in the main thread
QThread thread;
```

Here is a snippet from the initialization method of the class that runs in the main thread:

```
// Create the class that runs in the other thread and move it there
CServerThread * server = new CServerThread;
server->moveToThread(&thread);

// When the thread terminates, we want the object destroyed
connect(&thread, SIGNAL(finished()), server, SLOT(deleteLater()));
thread.start();
```

In the destructor for the class that runs in the main thread:

```
if(thread.isRunning())
{
    thread.quit();
    thread.wait();
}
```

What I expect to happen is the thread terminates and destroys the instance of the `CServerThread` class. However, the destructor for the `CServerThread` class is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`QThread::quit()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qthread.html#quit) stops the event loop for that thread.

> Tells the thread's event loop to exit with return code 0 (success).

But [`QObject::deleteLater()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#deleteLater) needs the event loop for the "owning" thread to be active:

> Schedules this object for deletion.
>   The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop.

So your object's destructor will not run, the `finished` signal is fired too late for that.

Consider the contrived example below:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <iostream>

class T: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        QThread thr;
        T() {
            connect(&thr, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(finished()));
        };
        void start() {
            thr.start();
            std::cout << "Started" << std::endl;
        }
        void stop() {
            thr.quit();
            std::cout << "Has quit" << std::endl;
        }
        void end() {
            thr.wait();
            std::cout << "Done waiting" << std::endl;
        }
    public slots:
        void finished() {
            std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

If you call:

```
T t;
t.start();
t.stop();
t.end();
```

The output will be:

```
Started
Has quit
Done waiting
Finished
```

`finished` is triggered after the `wait` is done. Too late for your `deleteLater` connection to be effective, that thread's event loop is already dead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... but isn't `deleteLater()` being invoked from the context of the main thread and not of the `QThread` I create?

Comment: The `finished` signal is emitted by your thread. Since your server also belongs to that thread, processing would happen in the thread, not the main thread. (See [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/threads-qobject.html) at the very bottom, `Auto Connection` description)

Comment: Wouldn't using `Qt::DirectConnection` cause the slot to run in the main thread? Which thread is emitting the `finished()` signal?

Comment: I believe the signal is emitted by your custom thread, not the main thread. If you touched your server from the main thread while it's still owned by your current thread, you're taking a big risk: the main thread doesn't own the object, your custom thread does. You'd probably need to reparent your object.

Comment: Would calling `delete server;` from the main thread be okay once the custom thread had terminated?